# VSCODE shows warnings as errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, linter

My VSCODE shows warnings as if they were errors (specifically linter warnings).

[image: warning message shows as error]

I want linter warnings to show with different unerline color. I tried modifying my `settings.json` adding the following configuration

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorError.foreground": "#ff0000",
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#ffc400",
        "editorInfo.foreground": "#35ffab"
    },
```

But it seems like VSCODE thinks that those are not warnings but errors

Comment: do you have any rule overrides in your .eslintrc.js? for example:  `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"]`

Comment: where can I find the .eslintrc.js file?

Comment: if you have one, it should be in the root of your directory. alternatively, it may be inside a `eslintConfig` field in your `package.json`

Comment: Found it. This is its content ```module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  overrides: [],
};
```

Comment: by default `@typescripy-eslint/no-unused-vars`'s level is error. you can set it to warning if you want ( see my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

Turns out for some reason the default Typescript linter (that shows warnings properly) was disabled.
Eslint was the culprit showing warnings as error (which makes sense, considering it's a linter that by definition should fail if there are lint issues)
After disabling ESLint and enabling the built in default validator (image attached)

[image: Enabling default validator]

Warnings show up correctly now (without red underlines/errors in the problems window)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

By default [`@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unused-vars/)'s level is error.

To downgrade this to a warning, you can change your `.eslintrc.js` :

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  rules: {
    ...
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["warn"]
  }
}
```

NB: You may have to restart your vscode to see the changes

Comment: The same thing happens with prettier and other linter warnings. I could add each of them individually to the .eslintrc.js like you suggest but this doesn't seem right. There must be a way to make warnings show up as warnings and errors as errors.

Comment: well these levels are defined in each individual linter / formatter.    what they declare as an error usually has rational behind it

Comment: in the errors tab can you see if any warnings appear ?   or is it just errors ?

Comment: They show up as errors in the errors tab. I find it very weird that prettier warnings would show up as errors by default

Comment: The issue was that the built in validator was disabled. Answer below